# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use two different script tag in one html Page. 1st script tag I used the js file location o use the function and in other script tag I have written another function.

in 2nd script there is  a function name CALCULATION which is called from the src file. but when I run the page it gives me **Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveProj is not defined at onload** error

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/calculation.js" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
function ActiveProj() { 
var startdate = '05/11/2017';
var endate = '08/15/2017';
calculation(startdate,endate);
}
</script>
<body onload="ActiveProj();">
```

Comment: you can use document ready function provided by jQuery by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to close the `script` tag by adding `</script>` after your `javascript` method, like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
  function ActiveProj() { .... }
 </script>
```

also put a closing tag on the other one, don't use a self closing tag.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/calculation.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already did in my code. I forgot to add that line in this question. @fujy

Comment: Are you calling that method in any other place?

Comment: @RohilPatel also put a closing tag on the other one, don't use a self closing tag.

Comment: Can you try using `window.load` like the example in the following link and check if you are still getting the same error
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload